# How to use first/head and rest/tail with Swift?

Tags: swift, recursion, functional-programming, swift3, tail

In order to use Swift in a functional style, how should we be dealing with `head` and `tail`s of lists? Are `Array`s and `ArraySlice`s appropriate (seems like it since an `ArraySlice` is an efficient mechanism to get sublists)? Is the right mechanism to convert an `Array` to an `ArraySlice` and use `.first!` and `.dropFirst()` as equivalents for `head` and `tail`?

As an example of adding a list of numbers:

```
func add(_ nums: ArraySlice<Int>) -> Int {
    if nums.count == 0 {
        return 0
    } else {
        return nums.first! + add(nums.dropFirst())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Array`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array) has an initializer ([`init(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1538750-init)) that can produce an `Array` from any [`Sequence`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence), such as an [`ArraySlice`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/arrayslice). However, using it forces a copy of the array data, which makes a simple sum algorithm like this to actually have `O(nums.count^2)` performance, even though it looks like it's only scanning through the array once.

```
func sum(_ nums: [Int]) -> Int {
    guard let head = nums.first else { return 0 } //base case, empty list.
    return head + sum(Array(nums.dropFirst()))
}

let input = Array(1...10)
let output = sum(input)
print(output)
```

To get around this, a better implementation would instead just operate on `ArraySlice`s, allowing copy-less slicing, but that requires the input `Array` first be converted into an `ArraySlice`. Luckily, an inner function can help make this transparent to the public API, but it does make the code longer.

```
func sum(_ nums: [Int]) -> Int {
    func sum(_ nums: ArraySlice<Int>) -> Int {
        guard let head = nums.first else { return 0 } //base case, empty list.
        return head + sum(nums.dropFirst())
    }
    return sum(ArraySlice(nums))
}
```

But really, as [matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/matt) said, don't do this. The head/tail approach to programming makes sense in a language that facilitates it well with pattern matching, good compiler optimizations, tail call optimization, etc. Swift's design encourages using `reduce`. Not only is it shorter and much more readable, but it's also more performant.

For comparison, here's what a typical Swift approach would be to this:

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element: Integer {
    func sum() -> Iterator.Element {
        return self.reduce(0, +)
    }
}
```

- It's simpler and shorter.
- It's polymorphic, so it'll work with any `Sequence`, rather than just being limited to `Array`
- It's generic over any `Integer` type, not just `Int`. So these all work:

  ```
  print(Array<UInt  >(1...10).sum())
  print(Array<UInt8 >(1...10).sum())
  print(Array<UInt16>(1...10).sum())
  print(Array<UInt32>(1...10).sum())
  print(Array<UInt64>(1...10).sum())
  print(Array< Int  >(1...10).sum())
  print(Array< Int8 >(1...10).sum())
  print(Array< Int16>(1...10).sum())
  print(Array< Int32>(1...10).sum())
  print(Array< Int64>(1...10).sum())
  ```

However, if you insist on taking this head/tail approach, you can try one of these two techniques:

```
extension Collection {
    func headTail1<Head, Tail, ReturnType>(_ closure: (Head?, Tail) -> ReturnType) -> ReturnType 
        where Head == Self.Element, Tail == Self.SubSequence {
        return closure(self.first, self.dropFirst())
    }

    func headTail2<Head, Tail>() ->(Head?, Tail)
        where Head == Self.Element, Tail == Self.SubSequence {
        return (self.first, self.dropFirst())
    }
}

func sum1<C: Collection, I: Numeric>(_ nums: C) -> I
    where C.Element == I {
    return nums.headTail1 { head, tail in
        guard let head = head else { return 0 } //base case, empty list
        return head + sum(tail)
    }
}

func sum2<C: Collection, I: Numeric>(_ nums: C) -> I
    where C.Element == I {
    let (_head, tail) = nums.headTail2()
    guard let head = _head else { return 0 } //base case, empty list
    return head + sum(tail)
}

print(sum(Array(1...10)))
```

This code abstracts away the details of how the list is split into its head and tail, letting you write `sum` by only worrying about the `head` and `tail` that are provided for you.

Comment: Interesting extension to the `Array` class. `reduce` doesn't solve all iteration and recursion needs, so that's not relevant.

Comment: @at. Have I answered your question?

Comment: Yes, I was hoping for a more elegant `head` and `tail` mechanism in Swift, but maybe this is as elegant as it gets..

Comment: This is like expecting swift to have GOTO because assembly does: There are very compelling reasons against it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your example is that you *wouldn't* use `head` and `tail` to add a list of numbers. You'd call `reduce`:

```
let nums = [1,2,3,4,5]
let sum = nums.reduce(0,+)
```

So, while I'm as fond of LISP / Scheme as the next man, you'll need a more compelling case of when we *need* `head` and `tail`, given that we have `map`, `filter`, and `reduce` (and so on).

Comment: That was a sample for instructional purposes.

Comment: That's what I said. It's not a good sample. You need a more compelling case.

Comment: @matt ok then demonstrate an implementation of  `reduce` – i fail to see why a basic recursive function that iterates thru a list is not a "compelling case" just because `reduce` exists.

Comment: It's because `reduce` _is_ functional, and we don't _need_ to recurse to do this. I love LISP but Swift is _not_ LISP, so it seems silly to pretend it is (or should be).

Comment: @naomik Reduce is: faster, simpler, shorter, more familiar. What else do you need? The recursive approach literally has nothing going for it, apart from some arbitrary desire to use recursion.

Comment: I am sure you are not a lisper, matt.